# how to align two images using DIV which has row and column spanning image and texts in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image

I have the below code and the css. The left image comes properly. However, when adding two images to the right side, it is showing one below the other and size bigger. So I have added styles rightImg with `object-fit: scale-down;` which reduced the size to some extent, but it is not coming side by side like columns. And still there is more space around the images, it is not aligned to left, top.

```html
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className={styles.Content}>
    <img src={imgUriL1} />
    <div className={styles.rightside}>
      <p>
        first text1
        <br />
        second text2
        <br />
        Third text3
        <br />
      </p>
      <div classname={styles.rightImg1}>
        <img src={imgUriR1} />
      </div>
      <div classname={styles.rightImg2}>
        <img src={imgUriR2} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

CSS

```
.Content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  img {
    min-height: 270px;
    max-height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .rightside {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 8px;
    p:first-child {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    p {
      margin: 8px 0;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
}

.rightImg1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
  }
}

.rightImg2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 150;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .Content {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 15px;
    img {
      min-height: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .rightside {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The display should be like below. The right side images are bigger in size and they should reduce the size to fit into the cells below. Any help highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a snippet using flex width instead of the set widths you had so you can get an idea of the structure. I also added some basic borders, again so you can see the structure. I replaced the images with text and destructured the CSS to default CSS for demonstrative purposes.

If you want to make the right images side by side, make sure to wrap it in a parent container and add display flex to the parent (which automatically puts the children in a row). Using flex to determine widths makes the content flexible and evenly spaced. For example, setting the left content to flex: 1 and the right content to flex: 2 makes it so the right content takes up 2x the space of the left content

```css
.Content {
  display: flex;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.leftImg {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
  .leftImg img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .rightside {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 8px;
  }
  .rightside p:first-child {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
   .rightside p {
      margin: 8px 0;      
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      flex: 1;
    }  
.allRightImgs {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.rightImg1 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.rightImg1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

.rightImg2 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-end;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.rightImg2 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .Content {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 15px;
   
  }
  .leftImg {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
    .rightside {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class="Content">
      <div class="leftImg"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537151608828-ea2b11777ee8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1878&q=80" /></div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <p>first text1<br/>
        second text2<br/>
        Third text3<br/>
        </p>             
        <div class="allRightImgs">
          <div class="rightImg1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523480717984-24cba35ae1ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" /></div>
          <div class="rightImg2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587300003388-59208cc962cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is there a way to make the third image height half as that of second image?

Comment: By second and third image do you mean the 2 images on the right? I made an edit to my post where I made the third image half the height of its container, which would be half the height of the second image (since both images are located within the same container aka same height). The key code for this is just defining the height of the third image container to be 50%

Comment: Yes.this reduced the height, but the the image got aligned to top. Can we place it bottom aligned?

Comment: I see, in that case, undo my previous edit about the height and keep the container height at 100%. Instead, what you can do is style the img tag by changing its height to 50%, and then in the parent container, add the flex property "align-items: flex-end" which makes the children (in this case image 3) always align at the bottom. I have edited my post

Comment: The height got reduced, but strange that the image is still at the top. Is there any other way other than align-items ?

Comment: Strange that it does not work for you. Another method could be setting the parent container to position: relative; and then adding "position: absolute; bottom: 0;" to your img element. Does that help?

Comment: It does not help. I will check your first option again. But just one quick question. I have <p> text third3 </p> Can we get a different style(different font size and color) to the value 'third3'? But the entire content 'text third3' should be in one line. <p> or <div> is fine.

Comment: If you wrap the "third3" in a span tag, it will stay as one line because span has a display of inline-block. That way, you can target the span and style it how you like. The first option should work, I tried to make it as similar to your current html structure. Maybe try to check if there is any other CSS overruling the flex styling

Comment: thanks. btw, there is an issue with the first big image on the left. The left image changes randomly and when a new image is used,its Div still shows width 320px but the image width exceeded and overlapped with the paragraph texts. How we can avoid this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219502/discussion-between-xenvi-and-ratheesh-vijay).